# How can I get TypeScript to always ignore importing Lightning Web Components?

Tags: lightning-web-components, typescript

We're experimenting with TypeScript and one of the false errors it's reporting is when importing Lightning Web Components because it can't find the `c` directory:

[image]

Obviously we can disable this by prepending the line with `// @ts-ignore`, but is there a way to disable this particular error checking by TypeScript across all the LWC files?

Comment: We use typescript extensively and we've made definitions for all our components. We also use 2nd generation packaging and each package is in a separate repo. We use github npm packages to share type definitions

Comment: @TemporaryFix, can you elaborate on how you use definitions to prevent the above error?

Comment: You specify where to grab the types in a tsconfig.json file. Specifically the `"paths"` attribute https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths

Comment: Just an observation if this is the case. If you are importing a component just for its CSS classes, you can create the CSS file in the component's folder and use `@import "c/styling";`, for example (where "styling" is the css-only component), instead of importing the component in the JS file.

Comment: @TemporaryFix Does this mean we'd need to create a `d.ts` file for each LWC in whichever path we specify?  ie. for the question here, we'd probably create a `utils.d.ts` file in the `lwc` folder, rather than having a `d.ts` file in the `lwc/utils` folder.

Comment: @NickC That's correct. We write our components in typescript which makes ts automatically understand the components when they're imported and used in other components. But if you are writing `.js` components then you need to create an accompanying `.d.ts` definition